# Install iOS app from ipa file (since not available in app store anymore)

Tags: ios-appstore, ios

Some years ago I bought the app "Infuse Pro 4" for iPad. Now it has a new version 5 and for some reason the 4 version is not available on the App Store anymore.

I tried iOS 11 beta and then I switched back to the latest iOS 10 version. But since I didn't make a backup before I has to do it by installing a clean version provided by Apple. So all my data and installed apps were gone.
Then when I started installing all my iPad apps one by one from the App Store. And then I figured out Infuse Pro 4 is not there anymore.

In the internet I was able to find an ipa file from the latest 4 version. I'm able to import it in iTunes. iTunes shows as it is possible to install the app but after disconnecting the device from my MacBook the app is not shown on my iPad.

Can you tell my why the app doesn't appear on my iPad although showed properly in iTunes and is there another method to install the app from ipa?